# Saving data on excel

Tags: excel, arduino

Is it possible to save on different excel sheets after a number of data collected?
I am data logging using Arduino in real time and I am aiming to create a new sheet every day.  Or at least is it possible to change the name of the .csv?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a function that formats the data as CSV on the Arduino side and then prints it out on the serial monitor. You can then copy the output on the serial monitor and paste it into a .csv file. You could also write a small program that takes the output on the serial monitor and then saves it to a .csv file. Here is an example of the code on the Arduino side

```
void print_data(int x, int y)
{
    Serial.print(x, DEC); 
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(y, DEC);    
    Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: because i may not be connected serially to a pc all the time... i m planning to save data on an sd card

Comment: How did you connect the Arduino to a SD Card? Are you using a shield or external hardware to save to the SD Card?

Comment: using a shield that is placed on top of the arduino

Comment: Oh then specify that in the question next time. I was assuming that you were outputting to the serial monitor. Then you would need to write functions (like the one I included in the answer) that would format a string in the CSV format and then output the formatted string (using the shield library) to the SD Card.